# Secure Golden Boot Key - am I vulnerable?

Tags: secure-boot

I'm an Arch Linux user. I'd like to protect myself from the live-usb hack by using SecureBoot:

1. Create my own Platform Key and sign the kernel with my own key.
2. Delete the Microsoft PKs
3. Enable SecureBoot

It is possible as described [here](http://blog.hansenpartnership.com/owning-your-windows-8-uefi-platform/)

But now there are golden keys for SecureBoot [available](http://thehill.com/policy/cybersecurity/290947-researchers-crack-microsoft-feature-say-encryption-backdoors-similarly) allowing **any** signed kernel to be run with SecureBoot. Two questions arise

1. Is it possible to check if my version of SecureBoot is vulnerable (as I see, the policies system was developed when the SecureBoot had already been introduced)
2. If my SecureBoot rejects the Microsoft PKs, am I still vulnerable? If the policy rule is signed, it's surely signed with the Microsoft key.

Comment: If the attacker has physical access to your machine, they can make your machine vulerable, you don't provide any information to determine if your currently vulerable though.